# SCRAPY SPIDER - Send Post Request

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrap the table of this webpage (https://www.ftse.com/pr oducts/indices/uk). When I inspect the page in the Network tab, I see this page fetches its data to an API with AJAX requests (type POST), which are done by the browser after the layout is loaded. So I am trying to build a spider which send POST requests to the webpage using the form_data given in the request. I have tested quickly with the following shell command and I get the data.

```
curl 'https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/home/ra_getIndexData/' --data 'indexName=GEISAC&currency=GBP&rtn=CAPITAL&ctry=Regions&Indices=ASX%2CFTSE+All-Share%2C%3AUKX%2CFTSE+100%2C%3AMCX%2CFTSE+250%2C%3AMCXNUK%2CFTSE+250+Net+Tax%2C%3ANMX%2CFTSE+350%2C%3ASMX%2CFTSE+Small+Cap%2C%3ANSX%2CFTSE+Fledgling%2C%3AAS0%2CFTSE+All-Small%2C%3AASXX%2CFTSE+All-Share+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AUKXXIT%2CFTSE+100+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AMCIX%2CFTSE+250+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3ANMIX%2CFTSE+350+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3ASMXX%2CFTSE+Small+Cap+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AAS0X%2CFTSE+All-Small+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AUKXDUK%2CFTSE+100+Total+Return+Declared+Dividend%2C%3A&type='
```

However when I try to code it on the spider using FormRequest classes the spider fails.

```
class FtseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ftse'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.ftserussell.com', 'www.ftse.com']
    start_urls = [
            'https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/uk']


    def parse(self, request):
        # URL parameters for the requst
        data = 'indexName=GEISAC&currency=GBP&rtn=CAPITAL&ctry=Regions&Indices=ASX%2CFTSE+All-Share%2C%3AUKX%2CFTSE+100%2C%3AMCX%2CFTSE+250%2C%3AMCXNUK%2CFTSE+250+Net+Tax%2C%3ANMX%2CFTSE+350%2C%3ASMX%2CFTSE+Small+Cap%2C%3ANSX%2CFTSE+Fledgling%2C%3AAS0%2CFTSE+All-Small%2C%3AASXX%2CFTSE+All-Share+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AUKXXIT%2CFTSE+100+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AMCIX%2CFTSE+250+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3ANMIX%2CFTSE+350+Index+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3ASMXX%2CFTSE+Small+Cap+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AAS0X%2CFTSE+All-Small+ex+Invt+Trust%2C%3AUKXDUK%2CFTSE+100+Total+Return+Declared+Dividend%2C%3A&type='`
        # convert the URL parameters in to a dict 
        params_raw_ = urllib.parse.parse_qs(data)
        prams_dict_ = {k: v[0] for k, v in params_raw_.items()}
        # return the response
        yield [scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/home/ra_getIndexData/',
                    method='POST',
                    body=prams_dict_)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the data has nested dictionaries it can not be represented as formdata in scrapy, we must pass the json dump in the body of the request which is equal to the initial representation of the "data". Also use yield from when yielding an iterator or use a single object or Request to yield instead.

```
yield from [scrapy.FormRequest('https://www.ftse.com/products/indices/home/ra_getIndexData/',
                method='POST', body=data)]
```

Comment: I have tried it but still get errors. I have noticed on the terminal it says: TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got dict
2018-10-02 15:45:52 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spid . It could be that formdata is not parsed correctly? But It is a dictionary

Comment: ok try replacing the formdata back to body and pass "data" as it is. if this works then i ll explain the reasoning.

Comment: since the data has nested dictionaries it can not be represented as formdata in scrapy, we must pass the json dump in the body of the request which is equal to the initial representation of the "data". also, i have updated my answer, please mark it as accepted. you are welcome.

Comment: Actually it works also with formdata as value but the reason it started to work is that I have changed yield to return. I am not sure now what is the difference since I generate only one FormRequest? Would be also possible to generate request for only a subset of data as now I think I get all the data in the raw Json ?

Comment: ahh i see. yield is used to return a single object or request. but in your case you are yielding a list.. try using `yield from [ ]` or `yield FormRequest()` instead.